# In SSRS is there a way to make a Row Group expand based on parameter value?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008

I've got a table with 5 columns, the first 3 of which allow the user to drill down through the levels of detail. Each of these columns (Region, Country & Office) has an associated Parameter so the user can select the geographic region for their report. Each parameter allows the selection of multiple values.

If the user selects 1 Region, 1 Country and 1 Office it's not exactly ideal for them to then have to expand each selection. Is there an expression I can enter somewhere to state that if only 1 value is entered in a parameter then that data set will automatically show as expanded?
This is in SSRS 2008 R2 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Group Properties for the detail group you can enter an expression for the initial visibility. Right now you probably have that set to "Hide." The expression needs to return a Boolean and could be something like:

```
=Parameters!Country.Count <> 1
```

This will have SSRS hide those rows if more (or less) than one value are selected in the parameter `Country`

But I have seen some unexpected results with this: test thoroughly. In my experience, BIDS handles these better than SSRS itself, so just when you think you've got it all working, it fails miserably once deployed. (Reason number 14 to have a test folder on production SSRS.)

Comment: Thanks for this...exactly what I was looking for (though as you suggest will be testing thoroughly before releasing my reports to the wider world).